# Buttons component not showing in rowTemplate in CodeRad

Tags: codenameone

Am trying to add buttons component to component in rowTemplate but this is not being displayed as would expect.
I expect to see an overflow button icon especially since I have specified a limit of 1.

XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <border view-controller="MyGroupsPageViewController"
            rad-model="GroupModel"
            ...
        <define-category name = "MAIN_MENU"/>
      
         
        <entityList layout-constraint="center" name="groups" addAction="CREATE_GROUP_ACTION"
            provider="com.mgr.app.providers.MgrGroupsProvider.class">
            <row-template>
                <border uiid="groupContainer">
    
                    <border layout-constraint="north">
                        <radLabel tag = "GroupModel.groupName" layout-constraint="north" component.uiid="GroupNameLabel"/>
                        <radSpanLabel tag = "GroupModel.groupDescription" layout-constraint="center" component.uiid="GroupDescriptionLabel"/>
                    </border>
                    <buttons actionCategory="MAIN_MENU" layout-constraint="south" uiid="GroupsButton" limit="1" layout="BoxLayout.y()"/>
                </border>
            </row-template>
    
        </entityList>
    
    </border>
```

Controller

```
...
        protected void initControllerActions() {
            super.initControllerActions();
    
            ActionNode.
                    builder()
                    .label("Contribute")
                    .addToController(this, MyGroups.MAIN_MENU,this::contribute);
            ActionNode.
                    builder()
                    .label("Group Transactions")
                    .addToController(this, MyGroups.MAIN_MENU,this::groupTransactions);
            ActionNode.
                    builder()
                    .label("My Transactions")
                    .addToController(this, MyGroups.MAIN_MENU,this::myTransactionsInAGroup);
    
            ActionNode.
                    builder()
                    .label("Exit Group")
                    .addToController(this, MyGroups.MAIN_MENU,this::exitGroup);
```

Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of minor points that might help.
With limit=1, it will only render a button that will show the rest of the actions in an overflow menu.  What happens if you change to limit=2?

It is also possible that the layout isn't giving it enough room.  See what happens with you set preferredH="20mm" on the  tag.

Comment: Still getting the same result with only change the height of the buttons component

Comment: Were you able to hack this issue?

Comment: @ngosti This may have been connected to https://github.com/shannah/CodeRAD/issues/21 which was fixed in 2.0.2 (although you should skip to 2.0.3 which is the latest)